# Continuously Updating Data Algorithm

Tags: auto-update, notify, continuous

There is information on a website that is neatly listed and every so often (not on a set schedule) it updates with new information. I am wanting to write a quick script that will automatically let me know when something new has been updated instead of letting me know every x-amount of house/minutes.

My initial thought was that I would have the script pull all the information I was looking for and store it in a list and on the next scan create a new list and get rid of all duplicates which would leave me with what the new information is.

If you know of an effective way to go about such things and could lead me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

I'm not really looking for source code, just how to go about it and I'm sure I can put it together after some guidance on an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poll the website, there is no real way you can register a change listener.

If you are ready to poll then document.lastModified (*js*)  can help.

Of course if your website have rss feeds then you can listen for changes.

or there are some free services that will send you an email notification if you register for their services. things (eg: http://www.followthatpage.com/)

Comment: Ah alright, so if the site doesn't belong to me, then the best thing to do would be have it scan every x-amount of hours/minutes?

Comment: Most commonly available tool are based on polling. The best alternative is to use a monitoring service like ChangeDetection and register for an RSS feed when the site of interest changes. Here is a google result (ghacks.net/2009/09/07/monitor-website-changes), that you might find interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the information it is quite helpful. I'll go ahead and read a bit more into it and check back later.